# Wampserver is not starting after adding a line in the httpd.conf

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server, wamp

The computer is Windows 7 Integral Edition.

I installed successfully wampserver `wampserver2.5-Apache-2.4.9-Mysql-5.6.17-php5.5.12-32b`. The Visual C++ redistributable library is also installed. There is PostgreSQL on the computer. So I added this line at the end of the `httpd.conf`:

```
LoadFile "C:/Programmes/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/libpq.dll"
```

Then I restarted wampserver , but it did not turn to green color , just stoped at the orange color ! So what is wrong in what I wrote ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you’d have to look at Apache’s error log, wherever that may be by default with WAMP.

In this case, the issue might be rather simple, instead: Don’t be confused by localized path names in Explorer.

Try this:

```
LoadFile "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/libpq.dll"
```

Comment: Yes ! it works ! So why is it still `Program Files` which is the correct directory name ?

Comment: Starting with Windows Vista (or maybe 7), Microsoft finally introduced localized folder names. Every folder you see with a non-English name actually has an English name. The resource pointer is stored in super hidden `desktop.ini` files.